# How to create dynamic table 4 columns per row using GridView?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

Hello I'm new to c# and bootstrap, I want to style my table like on the picture below using gridview and make it responsive, and I don't know how to implement it.

aspx code:

```
<div class="table-responsive"> 
    <asp:GridView runat="Server" id="data" CssClass="table table-hover table-bordered"/>
</div>
```

css code:

```
.table-responsive{
    margin: 20px;
}
```

[image]

But the output of my table looks like this
 [image]

Comment: Check this http://www.sitepoint.com/easy-responsive-css-grid-layouts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot realize that structure with a `GridView`. What you really need is a `FormView`. Inside the `FormView`'s `ItemTemplate` define a `table` with your required markup.

MSDN Url: [Using the FormView's Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288035.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Not much idea about c#, but with bootstrap you can use classes `row` and `col-sm-3`, `col-md-3`, `col-lg-3` for different views.

```
<div class="table-responsive"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">section1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">section2</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">section3</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">section4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Form more help http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid